# I get an error when trying to create an object using ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<T>(Vector3)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, constructor, game-development

Every time I add an argument to my parameter in Character.cs which is basically trying to create an object of a class that uses an interface so that I can use the methods of said class to implement a function:

```cs
Lmovements left = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Lmovements>(position);
```

I get the error:

> No overload for method 'CreateInstance' takes 1 argument

This is my code:

**Lmovements.cs:**

```cs
public class Lmovements : ScriptableObject, Commandclass.Execute 
{
    Vector3 cdirection;
    float speed = 3f;

    public Lmovements(Vector3 direction)
    {
        cdirection = direction;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        cdirection.x += speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

**Character.cs:**

```
public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    float speed = 3f;

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 position = transform.position;
        
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            //position.x += speed * Time.deltaTime;

            Lmovements left = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Lmovements>(position);
            left.Execute();
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            position.x -= speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            position.z -= speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            position.z += speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        transform.position = position;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are providing a `position` as an argument to the `ScriptableObject.CreateInstance` method which is not allowed.

First of all, `ScriptableObjects` are data containers in Unity and they can't be instantiated into the scene, which means you can't set them up `position`

Second, you must create your `ScriptableObject` in the Editor and reference them into the `Monobehaviour` script attached to some GameObject on the scene

The easiest way to create `ScriptableObject` is to add `CreateAssetMenu` as shown below

```
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Lmovement", fileName = "Lmovement")]
public class Lmovements : ScriptableObject
```

And after that, you will get the option for creating as you can see in the image below

[image]

Comment: How would I be able provide 'position' as an argument? How can I create objects witth arguments in them?